# How to replace specific object value in a column with a list?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column named 'Year'.

```
Year 
0  2000
1    DA
2  1998
3    DA
4  1999
```

I also have a list of years `list = ["1999", "2000"]`

**I want to replace "DA" values with the list**

```
Desired Output:
Year
0  2000
1  1988
2  1998
3  2019
4  1999
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
lst = ["1988", "2019"]

df.loc[df["Year"].eq("DA"), "Year"] = lst
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Year
0  2001
1  2022
2  1988
3  1998
4  2019
```